# PAPR for psk with a rectangular pulse in Matlab

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I generate a bpsk moudlation

```
N=1e4;
bits=randi([0,1],N,1);% наши биты
 bpskModulator = comm.BPSKModulator;
 bpskModulator.PhaseOffset = pi/16;
 modData = bpskModulator(bits);
```

And a rectangle

```
Rc = 1e2; % [b/s] chip rate
T =1; % [s/b] inverse of chip rate
Tc = 0.5* T;
Fs = 2e2; % [Hz] sampling frequency
dt = 1/Fs; % [s]  
ov1 = Fs/Rc;   % sampling factor
sps = 10;
dt2=dt/sps;
t = [0:dt2:2*T];  % [s]
 pulse_rect = rectpuls(t,T) ;
```

Now I want to make a bpsk convolution with a rectangle

```
n=upsample(modData,2);
 signal1 = conv(pulse_rect,n);

    signal=signal1';
```

My PAPR should come out equal to one, but when I count it's more than one. What am I doing wrong

```
pb = max(abs(signal));
avb = mean(abs(signal));
PAPR = pb/avb
```

Comment: Oh, I forgot to add, thank you

Comment: If I understand your intent correctly, you should insert as many zeros between the symbols as the length of the rectangular pulse minus 1. As it stands, you insert just one zero, so the symbol period is 2 samples, which is much shorter than the rectangular pulse